# Cannot resolve configuration property 'spring.data.solr.host'

Tags: java, spring, solr, dependencies

After I added the dependencies to my app, I am trying to set the host for the solr connection  in my application.properties file but it tells me that the configuration property is not recognised.
These are my dependencies:

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-solr</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.15</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-solr</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.13</version>
        </dependency>
```

I am suspecting that it is because of dependency missmatches but I have tried all possible versions.
I say that because when I am running the app I am getting the EntityInstantiators NoClassFound exception which is related to component's versions missmatch.

Comment: You are mixing Spring Boot 3.1 and 2.4 modules. That isn't goig to work. SOLR support has been dropped long time ago as well as maintaining Spring Data SOLR (https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-solr). Hence it isn't going to work with Spring Boot 3.1.

Comment: @M.Deinum so I should drop the spring-boot-starter-data-solr or downgrade the spring boot 3.1?

Comment: That is for you to decide. Spring Boot 2.4 isn't supported anymore as well. Read the link (and links in that link) as what to use (ElasticSearch for instance) instead of Solr.

Comment: So basically I am stuck because I really need to use Solr

Comment: Well downgrade to Spring Boot 2.4, but really reconsider SOLR. As Spring Data SOLR has been abandonded for quite some time already, ad Spring Boot 2.4 has been out of support for some time as well.

Comment: I will reconsider SOLR but thank you for the help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254937/discussion-between-cosmin-drgusanu-and-m-deinum).